# Disabling Spinner in android

Tags: android, spinner

I'm having problems when using `android:enabled="false"`, it's not **disabling** the **component** in the case it's a `spinner`. Don't know if it's relevant, but it belongs to a layout that's part of a `viewflipper`.

Any hints or workarounds ?

Thanks

Answer (score 119):

Disable or enable it before setting the adapter.

```
yourSpinner.setEnabled(false);   
yourSpinner.setClickable(false);  
yourSpinner.setAdapter(typeAdapter);
```

Comment: I haven't found that including `setClickable` is necessary, at least not on API 24. Has anyone found that it is on some other version of android?

Comment: More importantly, as of today, spinners don't respect the clickable attribute at all, whether it was set in XML or in code.

Comment: it has nothing to do with setting the adapter, you can do it before or after, it doesn't matter, why did you even mention it?

Comment: @user924 yes, it matters, after setting the adapter it does not work.

Answer (score 31):

It's not possible to enable/disable a Spinner in XML (yet).
To do so you have to do it in code.

Here's an example:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
spinner.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 20):

you can set `android:clickable="false"` in the `xml` to disable the `spinner` for click `event`.

Comment: Disabling using setEnabled(boolean) is more flexible than setting it inside XML

Comment: @Erick I'm not agree with you, it depends on use case

Comment: There is an Android bug that doesn't respect `clickable` for spinners.

Comment: tested with android 11 and not working.

Comment: This is also not work just you need to put it in class set enable = true or false

Answer (score 12):

You can set this in the Java code itself, instead of in the `XML`, because the `Spinner` should implement `setEnabled(boolean)` from `View`.

Comment: Will try it. Any known bugs when setting it in the xml ?

Comment: Worked with most of the spinners but some of them remained enabled.

Answer (score -1):

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
spinner.setEnabled(false);
```

Will not work

Actual code that will work ...

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
spinner.setEnabled = false;
```