# How disable spinner from another spinner?

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have 3 spinners
Spinner spinner1,spinner2,spinnerAorD;

```
spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SpeedActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, speedcutlist);


    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SpeedActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cctimer);


    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    spinnerAorD = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerAorD);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SpeedActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, AorD);


    adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerAorD.setAdapter(adapter3);
    spinnerAorD.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
 if(spinnerAorD.getId() == R.id.spinnerAorD)
        switch (position){

            case 0:
                AD = 0;
                break;
            case 1:
                AD = 1;
                spinner1.getSelectedView();
                spinner1.setEnabled(false);
                break;

        }
```

I am trying to disable spinner1 if AD =1, but it disables spinnerAorD itself not spinner1
requesting solution. thank you

Comment: May be `spinner1` also pointing `R.id.spinnerAorD`. Check it.

Comment: i hope this will be helps to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641879/how-do-i-make-a-spinners-disabled-state-look-disabled        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986130/disabling-spinner-in-android

Comment: Its coding mistake, Post full code so can understand easily.

Comment: my assumption is you may set likes this, `spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerAorD);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it guys thanks for the comments about Id changes leads me to the answer

```
 if (AD == 1){
        spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);//this line fixed it
        spinner1.getSelectedView();
        spinner1.setEnabled(false);

    }
```